# dotenv throw err internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800 cant find modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, mern, nodemon, dotenv

I just started learning mern stacks, it was all fine but then suddenly I can't run my nodemon server, I don't know what I did wrong so that my server won't run again. I already search for solutions but I can't find the answer.

**This is my server.js files**
[image: This is my server.js]

**This is the error message that I got:**

[image: This is the error message]

**Note: I'm using windows 10 x64**

Comment: If you started your server before editing `.env` try rebooting it.

Comment: i just tried your solution and it still won't run :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem , inside my **ads.js** there is a line like this

I'm not sure what is this syntax for

[image: error]

but all i do is remove that line and my server is working again [image]

Comment: i don't remember writting that line of syntax whatsoever